# Slice only the rows which have consecutive diff in column values

Tags: python

Below is the data

```
40  i
40  i+1  
41  i+2
38  i+3
38  i+4
40  i+5
40  i+6
41  i+7
41  i+8
..
37  i+n-1
40  i+n
```

I want to slice values as below

```
40  i      No
40  i+1    Yes
41  i+2    Yes
38  i+3    Yes
38  i+4    No
40  i+5    Yes
40  i+6    No
41  i+7    Yes
41  i+8    No
..
37  i+n-1  Yes
40  i+n    Yes
```

Basically where ever there is a change in value, I want to work only on those rows

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: Have you tried `df['col1'] == df['col1'].shift()` ?

Comment: @Erich , yes this is a DF , one of the column

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution in append , instead of i it should be i+1
and loc[0] should be appended before loop anyway for a start.

```
df=df.append(CHI.iloc[0])

for p in range(len(CHI["Price"])-1):

        if (CHI["Price"][p]!=CHI112["Price"][p+1]):
           df=df.append(CHI.iloc[p+1])
```